# How to create WebServices with a certificate in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, iis, x509certificate

task was given to me to build WebServices in VB.net (Using MS Visual WebDeveloper 2010 Express). I've built WS before, but this time, the requirement was to use server certification to secure WS. I've googled and googled and could not find a solution or explanation.

So far I've researched that IIS needs to be reconfigured, but that's about it. There are no examples that I could find on hosting the webservices.

Here is the server code I have so far:

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
Imports System.Net.Security
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Net

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
' <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Public Class MyWS
    Inherits System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol
    'Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
    Dim _log As String = ""

    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod(BufferResponse:=False)> _
    Public Function HelloWorld2() As String
        Dim resp As String = ""
        Try
            _log &= "Enter HelloWorld2" & vbCrLf



            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(resp) Then
                resp = "STRING IS EMPTY" & vbCrLf
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            resp = "SYSTEM ERROR: " & vbCrLf & ex.ToString & vbCrLf ' & "LOG:" & vbCrLf & _log
        End Try

        Return "LOG:" & vbCrLf & _log & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & resp
    End Function

    Public Sub New()
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf ValidateCertificate)
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = [Enum].Parse(GetType(SecurityProtocolType), GetAppSetting("SecurityProtocol", "Tls"))
        SetProxy()
    End Sub

    <ComVisible(False)> Public Sub SetProxy()
        WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = New System.Net.WebProxy()
    End Sub

Private Function ValidateCertificate(ByVal sender As Object, _
                         ByVal certificate As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate, _
                         ByVal chain As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain, _
                         ByVal sslPolicyErrors As System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
    _log &= "Enter ValidateCertificate: " & certificate.Subject & vbCrLf
    Log("Validating Certificate: " & certificate.Subject)
    Dim status As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatus

    '' If the certificate is a valid, signed certificate, return true.
    If sslPolicyErrors = System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None Then
        Return True
    End If
    '' If there are errors in the certificate chain, look at each error to determine the cause.
    If (sslPolicyErrors And System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors) Then
        If (Not chain Is Nothing) And (Not chain.ChainStatus Is Nothing) Then
            For Each status In chain.ChainStatus
                If (certificate.Subject = certificate.Issuer) And (status.Status = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot) Then
                    '' Self-signed certificates with an untrusted root are valid.
                    Continue For
                Else
                    If status.Status <> System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError Then
                        '' If there are any other errors in the certificate chain, the certificate is invalid, so the method returns false.
                        Return False
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
        '' When processing reaches this line, the only errors in the certificate chain are untrusted root errors for self-signed certificates.
        '' These certificates are valid for default Exchange server installations, so return true.
        Return True
    Else
        '' In all other cases, return false.
        Return False
    End If
End Function
End Class
```

Here is my client code:

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
Imports System.Net.Security
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Net

Partial Class TestPages_testWS
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


    Public Sub New()
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf ValidateCertificate)
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = [Enum].Parse(GetType(SecurityProtocolType), GetAppSetting("SecurityProtocol", "Tls"))
        SetProxy()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnTestWS_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTestWS.Click
        Dim ws As New MyWS
        Try
            ws.ClientCertificates.AddRange(GetCertificate("CertificateName"))
            txtOut.Text = ws.HelloWorld2()
        Catch ex As Exception
            txtOut.text = String.Format("EXCEPTION: [{0}]", ex.tostring)
        End Try
    End Sub

    <ComVisible(False)> Public Function GetCertificate(ByVal certName As String) As X509Certificate2Collection
        Dim result As X509Certificate2Collection = Nothing
        Dim store As X509Store = New X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine)
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly)
        result = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, certName, False)
        Return result
    End Function

    <ComVisible(False)> Public Function ValidateCertificate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal certificate As X509Certificate, ByVal chain As X509Chain, ByVal sslPolicyErrors As SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
        'Return True to force the certificate to be accepted.
        Return True
    End Function

    <ComVisible(False)> Public Sub SetProxy()
        WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = New System.Net.WebProxy()
    End Sub
End Class
```

This doesn't work because I can't even setup IIS properly. When I try to setup IIS, the SSL certificate list for binding of type https is empty. I am at a total loss what to do and how to proceed.

Do I need to configure IIS to use WS with a certificate? How do I do that? What would my server code look like to handle certificates?

Thanks for any insight.

**EDIT 1:** 
I fixed an issue, which was a logical one, and now I am properly getting `403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.` messages when trying to view the page without supplying certificate. However, there is another issue now. I seem to have access to the page with half of certs that I have installed on PC ( I am supplying one at a time and in the `oneToOneMappings` I added a single certificate. How come other certificates work too?

Also, even though there is a username and password on the certificate @ the `oneToOneMappings` section, it does not seem to matter if i supply that info in the credentials object before calling the WS: `ws.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(userName, userPass)`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using Client Certificates for authentication, your web service has nothing to do with any certificates. No need to change any code.

You should just use TSL(SSL) in IIS to secure the transport layer between the client and your service.

There is tons of information out there about setting up SSL on iis, e.g. [How to Set Up SSL on IIS](http://7http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis)

Comment: I went through that guide before posting my original request. I am still unable to figure things out. I have setup my WS to enable SSL and require certificate. But, whenever I call my webservice from a test page (whether on same machine or a different one) the webservice is responding positively, even if i do not supply a certificate

Comment: OK, i had a logical error (client call was on the same project as server code and it was calling server code directly, instead of instantiating webservice reference and executing the function from there) in my code and I fixed that. Now I have the opposite problem, I cannot get a proper response from WS - I always get forbidden